# JavaScript: Get Element by image src

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to programatically click an element that is only identified by its img src, like so:

```
<img src="images/x.jpg">
```

and I'm looking for something like

```
document.getElementBySrc('images/x.jpg').click();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do

```
document.querySelector("[src='images/x.jpg']").click()
```

Comment: Thanks, that does it. Strange though that this does not appear in the linked duplicate.